# How to create an outlook extension using Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, outlook

I need to create an outlook extension which should have a form with two buttons, and it should appear on the right side of the application, like how the todoist app does(red circled in the screenshot).

[image]

I tried creating using the "Outlook 2013 Add in" project type, I was able to create an add-in with some basic functionality, but did not know how do add a UI to it.

On little more googling, I found [this](https://www.add-in-express.com/outlook-extension), this looked like what I needed but didnt seem to be officially from microsoft/visual studio and appeared to be with some kind of fee too.

I am trying to make my first outlook extension.

Couldnt get any good results when I tried googling for the same, can anyone guide me in this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VSTO (nor Outlook) doesn't provide such layout for custom forms. However, you are free to use Windows API functions to subclass the Outlook window and inject your own forms. They call them as [Adjacent Windows In Outlook](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stephen_griffin/archive/2010/06/01/adjacent-windows-in-outlook.aspx). See the [Creating Adjacent Windows In Outlook](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Creating-Adjacent-Windows-00090e4a) sample code.

Add-in Express uses the same technology for subclassing Outlook windows. As a result you get a convenient way to place .net controls on a Windows form. For example, I have just tested a sample add-in with an advanced Outlook form placed to the **RightReadingPane** layout. And here is what I get:

[image: An advanced Outlook form]

Comment: Is this control written in c#. Coz when your second link shows a c++ project.

Comment: Yes, I used C# for developing the sample add-in.